# I need to add space between the video and the text on the right side of video

Tags: css, class, text

I need to add space between the video and the text on the right side of video. Im having trouble figuring it out the page is in an iframe i was able to put text to right of video now i need a buffer between also im using html5

```
 <div class="testimonials_inerbg">
                            <div class="testimonials_inerbg_right">
                            <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x4GWNZn5MK4?
 feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" align="left" width="300" height="200">
 </iframe>  </p>
 <p> Dr. Amin has taken  Parasitology to a  professional level of  expertise. 
    I have had    extremely ill patients who  have had negative stool  tests and 
    Dr. Amin has  found multiple parasites. His secret is to not use 
    destructive stains and to  simply look at the specimen. 
    He can even identify bugs by the ripple signature on the slide like a 
    good sonar operator can identify enemy submarines. Through his work, 
    Dr. Amin has helped me be a better physician.</p>
 <p>Dr. Bruce H. Shelton MD MD(H)</p>
 <p>President Arizona Homeopathic and Integrative Medical Association</p>
                            <h6>Dr Bruce H Shelton  
                            <br   />                                                                                                      
 </h6>
                            </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add padding to the right of the video (or left of the text) with `padding-right: 20px` and just adjust as needed. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ckpjthpu/
It's probably better to add the styling to an external stylesheet, of course, if you have one and are going to be repeating this style.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to do it in css and was getting lost that worked perfect

Comment: @BenSmith Accept as answer?